# Fetch a single word from an output in python?

Tags: python, linux

I need to fetch a single character from an output and put it in if statement.

I enter this

```
cloud_name = os.system(" curl ipinfo.io ")
print(cloud_name)

curl ipinfo.io                                                     127 ⨯
{
  "ip": "",
  "hostname": "broadband.actcorp.in",
  "city": "Bengaluru",
  "region": "Karnataka",
  "country": "IN",
  "loc": "",
  "org": "AS24309 Atria Convergence Technologies Pvt. Ltd. Broadband Internet Service Provider INDIA",
  "postal": "",
  "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
```

in this output i have to just check if Convergence is present in the org line.

How do i do that in python?

Comment: Python has its own `requests` module which would make this far easier

Comment: @Sayse, I wouldn't phrase it that way. `requests` isn't in the standard library. If anything, [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) is "Python's own" module to make this easier.

Comment: `os.system` does not let you capture the output. I agree that you'll probably want to use Python's native HTTP support to fetch a web page instead of using `curl` in this particular scenario, but if you are in a situation where you need to run a subprocess and capture its output, use the `subprocess` library. The `os.system` documentation also recommends this.

Comment: @Chris - good point, I've been using it for that long I forgot which was python's own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution which use solely elemnets of `python`'s standard library

```
import json
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://ipinfo.io') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print('Convergence' in data['org'])
```

Disclaimer: this code assumes that you do always get as response Object which has some `org`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```py
import requests


resp = requests.get("https://ipinfo.io")
if "Convergence" in resp.json().get("org", ""):
    print("yay")
```

---

*note*: This requires the installation of `requests` which is not in python standard library. It can be installed a few ways. One example is `pip install requests`, but here is the official [installation guide](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install)

Answer (score 1):

Using the *requests* module to GET the JSON response from that URL would be a better approach.

If however you insist on running *curl* you could do this:

```
import subprocess
import json

data = json.loads(subprocess.Popen('curl ipinfo.io', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, shell=True).stdout.read())
if 'Convergence' in data['org']:
    print('Convergence found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

This is how you could do it using *requests*:

```
import requests

(r := requests.get('https://ipinfo.io')).raise_for_status()

if 'Convergence' in r.json()['org']:
    print('Convergence found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'Convergence' in variable_name['org']:
    print('Do Something')
```

Note that JSON is not inside any varible. So do this:

```
x = {Your JSON file HERE}
```

so check it like this:

```
if 'Convergence' in x['org']:
    print('Do Something')
```